# Autocomplete input form from array JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

hi i need to create a form where when i put a batch_num, i would like that the other 2 input text in the form, autofill with materialname and materialCode taken from a query/array i found this but it give me the error that autocomplete function doesn't exist:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

How can i fix the error or make the autocomplete input?

```
$(function() {
var users = [{
    "email": "marie@gmail.com",
    "name": "marie"
}, {
    "email": "miss@gmail.com",
    "name": "miss"
}];

function handleAutocomplete(term) {
    // use 'term' for custom filtering etc.
    var options = $.grep(users, function(e){ return e.name.startsWith(term); });
    return options;
}
$("#name").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function(request, response) {
        var name = request.term;
        var data = handleAutocomplete(name); /* get answers from somewhere.. */
        response(data);
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        $("#name").val(ui.item.name);
        return false;
    },

    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#name").val(ui.item.name);
        $("#email").html(ui.item.email);
        return false;
    }
}).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
        .append("<a>" + item.name + "<br>" + item.email + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};
});
```

Comment: The error suggests that you didn't include the JavaScript file containing the autocomplete functionality into your page.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `<a>` in your Item Rendering. Please see: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

I tested your code, and it is working properly when you add the jQuery UI:

```js
$(function() {
  var users = [{
    email: "marie@gmail.com",
    name: "marie",
    label: "marie",
    value: "marie@gmail.com"
  }, {
    email: "miss@gmail.com",
    name: "miss",
    label: "miss",
    value: "miss@gmail.com"
  }];

  function handleAutocomplete(term) {
    // use 'term' for custom filtering etc.
    var options = $.grep(users, function(e) {
      return e.name.startsWith(term);
    });
    return options;
  }

  $("#name").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function(request, response) {
      var name = request.term;
      var data = handleAutocomplete(name); /* get answers from somewhere.. */
      response(data);
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      $("#name").val(ui.item.name);
      return false;
    },

    select: function(event, ui) {
      $("#name").val(ui.item.name);
      $("#email").html(ui.item.email);
      return false;
    }
  }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
      .append("<div>" + item.name + "<br>" + item.email + "</div>")
      .appendTo(ul);
  };
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div>
  <label>Name:</label><input id="name" type="text">
  <div>Email: <span id="email"></span></div>
</div>
```